# Downloading .imgc file to Pi 3 B

Tags: boot

Hi I ran my PI 3 B+ with only the SD-Card. I installed NOOB to the SD card then inserted it into my PI and downloaded Raspbian. Now my device boots fine. To get started on my project i need to download an .imgc file to the PI. I have the file on my computer but how do i download it to the PI. Can you assist in helping me do so? I heard i should use HDD Raw Copy Tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect the RasPi with an ethernet cable to the computer. Depending on the operating system on the computer a network connection may work out of the box. You can setup a WiFi access point on the RasPi and connect to it from the computer. How to do it you can look at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866). You can use bluetooth to connect to the RasPi. If you have established a connection you can just copy the file to the RasPi.

But the simplest should be to copy the file to an USB stick and plug it to the RasPi. Then you can direct access it on the USB stick, no need to copy it for installation.